# Retrieving all GridViewRow objects from a GridView control with paging enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I currently have a GridView control on my aspx page with paging enabled and I need to loop through the entire row collection/count to process the selected records.  With my current code, it will only loop through the current page of GridView row.

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Here is my current code:

ASPX page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20">
   <Columns>
      <!-- My Column list -->
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button id="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="MyButton_Click" />
```

code behind:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int Count = 0; Count < MyGridView.Rows.Count; Count++)
    {
        //The row count is 20 and only contains the GridViewRow object in the current page view  
        //I want to retrieve the all GridViews rows so I can add them to a ReorderList control
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes because your gridview UI is only aware of the current page.
Get the datasource and determine the row count from there...

```
        int count = ((DataTable)MyGridView.DataSource).Rows.Count;
```

//or

```
        int count = ((ICollection<SomeRecord>)MyGridView.DataSource).Count;
```

Comment: I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception when I use this code in my button click event.

Comment: Probably because when you are referencing it the object is no longer available.  You could try saving the count in ViewState at the time you assign the datasource to the gridview (using the above), and retrieve it when required again (in button click).

Comment: @CRice But storing the data in the viewstate beats the purpose of paging a bit, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jules a lot of assumptions about the question are being made here. Can't remember what my thinking was with the ViewState but it's likely the datasource will need to get requested again on postback and the count of items can be reassessed then.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the following code:

```
//Change gridview to
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind();

 //Transfer rows from GridView to table
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (GridView1.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count; j++)
        {
              //Add your code here..
        }
    }
}

//After filling your datatable change gridview paging style back to first, ie.

GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

This may help you, let me know if this was helpful for you...

Comment: No that would not work, as GridView1.Rows.Count refers only to a single page of rows, not the entire gridview's rows in other pages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should get the row count from your data source's row count.

If you need to filter rows, you can use DataTable's / DataView's **Select** method.

**EDIT :** You can not get actual row count by gridview.Rows.Count if gridview is paged. Depending on your comment, I assume that you're using listDataSource generic list to bind your gridview, you can get your row count as :

```
List<DataSourceItem> selectedRows = 
  listDataSource.FindAll(delegate(DataSourceItem item)
  {
      // Assuming you have a IsSelected bool property 
      // that refers your row is selected : 
      return item.IsSelected;
  });
  int rowCount = selectedRows.Count;
```

Comment: I am using a generic list of my custom class as my GridView's data source

Comment: Also, I need to add the selected records from this GridView and append them to an Ajax Control tool kit ReorderList control.

Comment: I update my answer, you can use selectedRows generic list for your ReorderList control.

Answer (score 0):

use session or state to store:

```
protected void Set_CheckboxStatus()
    {
        CheckBox selectall = (CheckBox)EmployeeGrid.HeaderRow.FindControl("gcb_selectall");
        ArrayList cbstatuslist = new ArrayList();
        if (Session["childcbstatus"] != null)
        {
            cbstatuslist = (ArrayList)Session["childcbstatus"];
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in EmployeeGrid.Rows)
        {
            int cb_index = (int)row.DataItemIndex;  //For Getting DataItemIndex of EmployeeGrid 
            //int cb_index = (int)row.RowIndex;
            CheckBox cb_selemp = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("gcb_selemp");
            CheckBox cb_active = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("gcb_active");

            if (cb_selemp.Checked == true)
            {
                if (!cbstatuslist.Contains(cb_index))
                    cbstatuslist.Add(cb_index);
            }
            else
            {
                cbstatuslist.Remove(cb_index);
            }
        }
        Session["childcbstatus"] = cbstatuslist;
    }
```

from the arraylist you can get all row index to loop and get the value from the gridview with paging.

Answer (score 0):

@CRice's answer should have been the official answer.

Here is my solution. You need to presave the gridview's data, via its `DataSource`, into `ViewState` or `Session`.

GridView.Rows only refers to the "visible" rows, or the page currently shown on the screen.

```
    protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

        DataSourceSelectArguments dss = new DataSourceSelectArguments();

    //get the datasource related to the gridview
    string wsDataSourceID = (gv.DataSourceID == string.Empty) ? ViewState["DataSourceID"].ToString() : gv.DataSourceID;
    SqlDataSource sds = (SqlDataSource)pnlMAIN.FindControl(wsDataSourceID);
    if (sds != null)
    {
        //load the data again but this time into a dataview object
        DataView dv = (DataView)sds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        if (dv != null)
        {
            //convert the dataview to a datatable so we can see the row(s)
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)dv.ToTable();
            if (dt != null)
            {
                //Save your data before changing pages
                ViewState["AllTheData"] = dt;

                gv.DataSource = dt;
                gv.DataSourceID = null;
            }
        }
    }

    //now change pages!
        gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
```

Next, when changing pages, here we save the data

```
protected void GridView_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

    DataSourceSelectArguments dss = new DataSourceSelectArguments();

    //reload the datatable back to the gridview
    gv.DataSource = ViewState["AllTheData"];
    gv.DataSourceID = null;
    gv.DataBind();
```

I hope the code speaks for itself.

Thanks